# how to create test plan in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

i'm a beginner in jmeter, I'm trying to make a test plan for test website (www.barablu.com), but i don't get what is server name means here? and do i need http request default for this?

thanks anyway
wait the reply

Answer (score 2):

It's all explained in the [jmeter web test plan manual entry](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/build-web-test-plan.html).

Answer (score 0):

I know this doesn't directly answer the question but it does answer the need.
As you are a beginner you should check out JMeter's proxy recording capabilities and simply record the actions you want for your script by using your web browser.

Answer (score 0):

Create a Test plan with the option available on top. Choose thread group. Add it.  Make your server settings.Port change is required.Also you can pass the URL else run directly without it too. you need to change it.

You can view the google page not working, that's when your J Meter is ready for usage.